# How to lookup a specific security certificate on my phone?

Tags: security, certificates

I have been trying to find out which security ca certificate is which on my phone, when they are all active my phone runs really slow.

Is there a way to find these certificates?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a CA certificate could make your phone slower, so perhaps the problem isn't what you think it is. What makes you think it's the certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Settings** app -> **Security** -> **Trusted Certificates** and you'll find all of them. Tap on an item and there's a "Disable" button available.